# How to run executable file in Ubuntu as a command or service (with Node.js child_process.spawn())?

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, executable

First, similar questions, no answers:

[Node.js child_process.spawn() fail to run executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461749/node-js-child-process-spawn-fail-to-run-executable-file)

[node.js child_process.spawn ENOENT error - only under supervisord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496015/node-js-child-process-spawn-enoent-error-only-under-supervisord)

I have an executable file with `.linux` extension. It is http server.

> service.linux

I can run it like this:

```
$ ./service.linux
2018/01/11 18:32:56 listening on port 8080
```

But since it is not a command, I cannot start it as a spawned process:

```
let cp = spawn('service.linux', [], { cwd: __dirname });
```

The errors I get is:

```
service.linux: command not found

ERROR: Error: spawn service.linux ENOENT
```

How can I run it as a command? Or should I use some other command to run it, like:

```
$ start service.linux
```

UPD:

```
$ file service.linux 
service.linux: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

UPD:

It needs absolute path:

```
const path = require('path');
let cp = spawn(path.resolve(__dirname, `service.linux`), [], { cwd: __dirname });
```

Comment: paste the contents of service.linux, which interpreter is being used to run service.linux ?

Comment: @AkhilThayyil, I can't. Its some binary file.

Comment: run this command "file service.linux" check and share the mime type

Comment: Updated the question. `ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped`

Comment: Have you tried using the relative path? i.e.: `let cp = spawn('./service.linux', [], { cwd: __dirname });`

Comment: This is a path issue, node is unable to find service.linux file, use absolute path, issue will be resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a path issue, node is unable to find service.linux file, use absolute path, issue will be resolved

Comment: Yes, you are right. Passing an absolute path solved the issue.
`path.resolve(__dirname, 'service.linux')`

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) and also write `./` before the name of the binary:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("./service.linux", (err, data) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Assuming the file is in the same directory as the script.

The error `ENOENT` means "Error No Entry" so it basically doesn't find the command.

That's why we specify `"./"`. That way it will handle it as a path.

Comment: I did. It blocks terminal. Terminal just hangs. No outputs, no event handlers starts. To break it, I run `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: @Green It doesn't really make the terminal hang. It just means that there is no data to show. Can you verify if the binary is running while the terminal "blocks"?